# Linux - ограничить доступ пользователя только его каталогом

Tags: linux, файлы, права, доступ

Подскажите, народ, как в Линукс сделать так, чтобы пользователь при запуске любых программ, работающих с файлами (файлменеджерами, браузерами, ftp-клиентами) Не мог выйти за пределы своей пользовательской папки?

Comment: `chroot` надо ему делать

Answer (score 3):

Он все равно сможет выходить в корень и читать и запускать файлы из системных папок - вроде /usr/bin/bash. Иначе система будет не работоспособна.

Скорее всего, вы хотите запретить ему смотреть каталоги других пользователей.
Тогда очень просто:

для всех папок в /home (не рекурсивно)

```
chmod go-rwx /home/<папка>
```